# Git error: cant execute git log && git diff [No such file or directory]

Tags: git

I just cloned a remote repository into my local VM.

When I run `git log` or `git diff`, it is showing

```
error: cannot run most: No such file or directory
```

I couldn't find any answer related to this issue in the web, thats why Im posting here. Any clues ??

Comment: I'm guessing you have your `core.pager` config set to `most`, is this correct?

Comment: Yep. looks like this is the problem here. read the below answer how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like git try to run program named most and cant find it.
Open your `~/.gitconfig` and you probably will see there incorrect settings pointing to most

#### ***`How to fix it?`***

The easiest way is simply to remove this configuration from the config file.
(delete the pager entry)

Another way is to set the desired pager :

```
# set vim as the pager handler
git config --global core.pager 'vim -'
```

---

#### Demo of simulating the problem and fixing it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks , but now it seems there is some encoding problem, characters like '^[' appears here and there in diff and log.

Comment: Can yo paste the config you have?

Comment: If you still have problems simply remove the page line form the file and it will use the default one. This will resolve your issue.

Comment: Yah I removed the pager line, it worked !! thnx alot